# JMeter 3.2 Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONManager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am using `JMeter 3.2` and for one of the request I have `JSON Exttractor` with `variable name` as `SenderId` and `JSON Path Expressions` as `$[0].selectedSender.id` and when I run the tests am seeing below exception, can someone please help me to fix this issue?

```
2017-07-26 14:43:34,902 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONManager
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor$1.initialValue(JSONPostProcessor.java:60) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor$1.initialValue(JSONPostProcessor.java:57) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor.threadFinished(JSONPostProcessor.java:242) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:679) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:997) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:997) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978) ~[jorphan.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:310) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Can you share you json post processor definition? Is it under a sampler?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the jmeter version above 3.0 need to install plugin

https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-json